# SVN set up and reintegrate feature

Tags: svn

Our customer wants to have the source code which we are developing at their end. As part of this, they have chosen SVN. They want us to develop code at their end.

They have come up with the following structure. The alphabets represent the branches.
Once DEV branch is done with the code accumulation, they want a new branch called QA to have that code so that QA team could start off their testing on it. If they find any bugs, the DEV Team updates the code in DEV branch and the QA would sync their code with DEV again.

Finally the code is released into production and if there are any bugs, the DEV-QA-Prod cycle will again follow.

```
A->B [DEV]----------
|\ |               |
|  C [ QA ]        |
|                  | 
|_______D[ PRODUCTION ]
```

We are relatively new to SVN. So, we have couple of questions in this regard.

1.Once QA is good to go, both B and C have the same code base more or less. Given this, which branch should be integrated back to A?. Is it B or is it C or does it not matter at all as both of them have the same stuff.

2.If it is indeed C, can we directly reintegrate the branch[C] of another branch[B] to parent[A]?

Thanks,
Pavan.`enter code here`

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but this helped me a lot when I was learning SVN - http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/05/06/day-to-day-with-subversion.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a `QA` branch if QA simply logs bugs against it, never actually touching the code and committing fixes to the branch. Why not give QA read-only access to the `DEV` branch? That way, you'd know you would only need to merge the `DEV` branch back into `trunk`.

If instead QA *does* need their own branch off `DEV`, because they will be committing fixes, then the merge path should be: `QA` -> `DEV` -> `trunk`.

I'm not sure why you are creating a `PROD` branch off `trunk` post-QA. Why not simply [tag `trunk`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html) with something like a version number or name describing the release? Then, assuming that development continues on the original `DEV` branch, and if a bug is found in production, you can either roll the fix up in the next release of `DEV` (merged back into `trunk` post-QA), or create a separate `DEV` branch off `trunk` at the tagged revision and apply the fix there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trunk` as the development checkout. The code in `trunk` should be the main copy, where bugfix and 'safe' development are performed.

Once you want the QA to do their work, create a new tag, giving it a version/build number.

When the QA finds a bug, the code on trunk is fixed. No further development must be done on trunk while the QA test is running.
Once the bugs are fixed, a new tag will be created, and QA test must be ran again.

If you want to develop new features while the QA test/bugfix cycle is running, you should create a new branch, merging it often from the trunk, in order to integrate all the bugfixes: the release of the new features will consist in the merge from the branch to the trunk and the creation of a new tag. And so on.

The QA could use the svn `switch` command to jump from a tag to another: I suppose they don't write code; a tag is meant not to be modified after its creation.